# Java Client/Server not displaying in ClientGUI

Tags: java, user-interface, client-server

Hi I've been working on a Server/Client Chat Program in which I need a GUI for the client . I've got the basic console Client/Server communicating correctly but I can't get the input/output of the client to display on the Client GUI can somebody please take a look and give me suggestions on as to how I can get the output of the Client to work on the ClientGUI using the text field as input and then broadcasting it to the text area? I've placed my code below.

**DATA OBJECT**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class DataObject implements Serializable{

String message;

public DataObject(){}

public DataObject(String message){

    setMessage(message);
}

public void setMessage(String message){

    this.message = message;
}

public String getMessage(){

    return message;
}
 }
```

**ThreadedChatServer**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ThreadedChatServer{
     ThreadedChatClient tcg;
     int port;
     public ThreadedChatServer(int port){
    this.port=port;
    try{

        ArrayList<ThreadedChatHandler> handlers = new ArrayList<ThreadedChatHandler>();
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);

        for(;;){
            System.out.println("Waiting for clients on port " +port+"..."); 
            System.out.println("If running client from console type 'java ThreadedChatClient [String Username] [String host] [int Port]'");
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("New user has entered.");    
            new ThreadedChatHandler(s, handlers).start();
        }



    }catch(Exception e){

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    ThreadedChatServer tcs= new ThreadedChatServer(1999);
}
  }
   class ThreadedChatHandler extends Thread{
        ThreadedChatClient tcg;
        public ThreadedChatHandler(Socket s, ArrayList<ThreadedChatHandler> list){

    this.s = s;
    this.list = list;
    this.list.add(this);
}

public synchronized void broadcast(DataObject d) throws IOException{

    for(ThreadedChatHandler handler: list){

        handler.oos.writeObject(d);

    }

}

public void run(){
    try{
      ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

      oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

      objIn= new DataObject( "User has entered.");  
      broadcast(objIn);
      while(true){

        obj = (DataObject)ois.readObject();
        broadcast(obj);
      }




    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        try{
            objOut= new DataObject("User has left.");
            broadcast(objOut);
            list.remove(this);
            ois.close();
            oos.close();
            s.close();
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
DataObject obj,objIn,objOut;
Socket s;
ArrayList<ThreadedChatHandler> list;
ObjectInputStream ois;
ObjectOutputStream oos;
}
```

**ThreadedChatClient**

```
DataObject in, out;
ObjectOutputStream oos;
ObjectInputStream ois;
Scanner scan;
String username;
ChatClientGUI cg;

public ThreadedChatClient(String username,String host,int port){

    this.username=username;
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    try{
        s = new Socket(host,port);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    this.start();

    for(;;){

        String temp = scan.nextLine();
        out = new DataObject(temp);
        try{            
            out.setMessage(username+": "+out.getMessage());
            oos.writeObject(out);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}



public void run(){
    try{
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    for(;;){
        try{
            in = (DataObject)ois.readObject();

        }catch(Exception e){

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println(in.getMessage());
    }

}


public static void main(String[] args){


    ThreadedChatClient c = new ThreadedChatClient(args[0],args[1],Integer.parseInt(args[2]));

 }
}
```

**ChatClientGUI**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ChatClientGUI extends Frame implements ActionListener{

Canvas c;
TextField tfServer,tfPort,tfUsername,tf;
TextArea ta;
int defaultPort;
String defaultHost,defaultUsername;
Label label;
Button b,b2;
List lst;
ThreadedChatClient cc;
int finalY,finalX;

public ChatClientGUI(String username,String host,int port){

    super("ChatClientGUI");
    defaultPort = port;
    defaultHost = host;
    defaultUsername= username;
    setSize(600,600);
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter (){
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    Panel nPanel = new Panel(new GridLayout(3,1));
    Panel serverAndPort = new Panel(new GridLayout());
    tfServer = new TextField(host);
    tfServer.addActionListener(this);
    tfPort = new TextField("" + port);
    tfPort.addActionListener(this);
    tfUsername= new TextField(defaultUsername);
    tfUsername.addActionListener(this);

    serverAndPort.add(new Label("Username:"));
    serverAndPort.add(tfUsername);
    serverAndPort.add(new Label("Server Address:  "));
    serverAndPort.add(tfServer);
    serverAndPort.add(new Label("Port Number:  "));
    serverAndPort.add(tfPort);

    nPanel.add(serverAndPort);

    label = new Label("Enter your message below");
    nPanel.add(label);
    tf = new TextField();
    tf.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    nPanel.add(tf);
    add(nPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    ////
    Panel cPanel= new Panel(new GridLayout(2,1));
    ta= new TextArea();
    cPanel.add(ta);
    ta.setEditable(false);
    c=new Canvas();
    c.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    c.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    c.setEnabled(true);
    cPanel.add(c);
    add(cPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);


    //////
    Panel sPanel= new Panel(new GridLayout());
    Panel inOutPanel= new Panel(new GridLayout());
    b= new Button("Login");
    b.addActionListener(this);
    b.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    inOutPanel.add(b);
    b2= new Button("Logout");
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    b2.setBackground(Color.RED);
    b2.setEnabled(false);
    inOutPanel.add(b2);
    lst = new List(4,false);
    lst.add("*List Of Users*");
    inOutPanel.add(lst);
    sPanel.add(inOutPanel);

    add(sPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object o= e.getSource();
    if(o==b){
        int por=0;
        por = Integer.parseInt(tfPort.getText());
        ta.append(tfUsername.getText()+" has entered the chat.\n");
        b.setEnabled(false);
        b2.setEnabled(true);
        tfUsername.setEditable(false);
        tfServer.setEditable(false);
        tfPort.setEditable(false);
        lst.add(tfUsername.getText());
        tf.setEditable(true);
        tf.addActionListener(this);
        cc= new ThreadedChatClient(tfUsername.getText(),tfServer.getText(),por);

    }
    if(o==b2){
        ta.append(tfUsername.getText()+"  has left the chat.\n");
        b.setEnabled(true);
        b2.setEnabled(false);
        tf.setEditable(false);
        tfUsername.setEditable(true);
        tfServer.setEditable(true);
        tfPort.setEditable(true);

        tf.removeActionListener(this);
        lst.remove(tfUsername.getText());
        }
    if(o==tf){
        DataObject objt=new DataObject(tfUsername.getText()+": "+tf.getText()+"\n");
        ta.append(tfUsername.getText()+": "+tf.getText()+"\n");
        tf.setText("");
    }
    if(o==c){
    c.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }


}


public static void main(String [] args){

    ChatClientGUI cc= new ChatClientGUI("unknown","localhost",1999);
    cc.setVisible(true);    

     }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @ns47731 CR is for *working code* - this question *came* from CR. The OP needs help getting their code to work, which is off-topic for CR and spot-on for SO. Please see CR's [Help Center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).